# Assign and display ranks to users from mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb, ranking

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_uid, s.ostats, s.attack, s.defense
FROM stats s JOIN
     users u 
     ON s.id = u.user_id
ORDER BY s.ostats DESC;
```

So in above data, "*ostats*"(overall) is just a sum of *attack+defense* and by using this query I could display users in descending order of their "ostats" values..

But how do I **assign and display** rank of each user, like the one with most "ostats" valued user as Rank 1 and the second highest "ostats" valued user as Rank 2 and so on..?

Comment: What is the use case of this? Do you want to output the result with ranking or just show it like that?

Comment: Wdym use case? I want to output the result with ranking

Comment: @i0N77 . . . Is `ostats` actually a column in the `stats` table?

Comment: Yes, ostats is a name of a column in stats table @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @iON77 i meant if you can attach the rank somwhere in the code rather than the SQL statement

Comment: That would be nice @Sens. Php code will do fine too, but I don't know where to begin, probably something to do with Increment operators, but how do I rank users using php code in order of their 'ostats' DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a variable to keep track of the row number?

```
SET @rank = 0;

SELECT 
    u.user_id,
    u.user_uid, 
    s.ostats, 
    s.attack, 
    s.defense,
    (@rank:=@rank + 1) AS rank
FROM stats s 
    JOIN users u on s.id = u.user_id 
ORDER BY s.ostats DESC;
```

Comment: I get the same error as listed above while using your query too.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a row number using variables:

```
SELECT u.user_id,u.user_uid, s.ostats, s.attack, s.defense,
       s.ranking
FROM (SELECT s.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as ranking
      FROM (SELECT s.* FROM stats s ORDER BY s.ostats DESC) s CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0) params
     ) s JOIN
     users u 
     ON s.id = u.user_id
ORDER BY s.ostats DESC;
```

In the event of ties, this will give different users different rankings.  If that is an issue, you can use this modified form:

```
SELECT u.user_id,u.user_uid, s.ostats, s.attack, s.defense,
       s.ranking
FROM (SELECT s.*,
             (@rn := if(@o = ostats, @rn,
                        if(@o := ostats, @rn + 1, @rn + 1)
                       )
             ) as ranking
      FROM (SELECT s.* FROM stats s ORDER BY s.ostats DESC) s CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0, @o := -1) params
     ) s JOIN
     users u 
     ON s.id = u.user_id
ORDER BY s.ostats DESC;
```

Of course, in MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()`, `rank()` or `dense_rank()` for this purpose.

Comment: I get an error when I used both of your queries, Please guide me as to where I went wrong with it? check the original post, where I've updated all the code I'm using to query and display it out

Comment: @i0N77 . . . What error are you getting?  What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: 10.1.34-MariaDB @Gordon Linoff